# Commenting System

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I am currently using userspice as a login system and I have already developed a html website, which is now linked to my website and I have create a blog on my website but I am having difficulty with my comment system of the blog, as I have tried every even looked for tutorial on how to make the comment system to function. I want it so that the comment system only appears when a user is logs into userspice and that they can only comment when they are logged into userspice. Also I want the comments to appear above the comment form after the user has hit submit.

In screen shot 1 you will see the way I wish my comment system to be. and on screenshot to you will see the design on my comment form but I need help with the above.

```js
<form>
    <div class="col-md-4 comment">
     <input type="text" value="Name" onfocus="this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value ='Name';}">
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 comment">
     <input type="text" value="Email" onfocus="this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value ='Email';}">
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4 comment">
     <input type="text" value="Subject" onfocus="this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value ='Subject';}">
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix"> </div>
 <textarea cols="77" rows="6" value=" " onfocus="this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Message';}">Message</textarea>
 <input type="submit" value="Send" >
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The way I want my form to be processed

[image: The way I want my form to be processed]

The way my form is using html

[image: The way my form is using html]

Answer (score 0):

Just glancing through the documentation, and they seem to reference this method when referencing users:

```
$userData = $user->data();
```

So I would do a `var_dump()` on that and see what you're getting out when you're not logged in, there's not much info on their site. A couple of other checks are:

```
$userId = $user->data()->id;
```

and

```
echouser($user->data()->id);
```

Again, I'm not sure what returns from those methods/functions, but in theory you could do something like:

```
if(empty($user->data())) {
  // not logged in, log in or register
} else {
  // logged in, show comment form
}
```

And a final note, with your inputs, you don't need the inline JavaScript, there is the `placeholder` attribute which does that for you and honestly unless you're supporting older browsers like IE 8, there's no need for the JS. Also don't forget to name your inputs so you can grab the data from the submit:

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Name" name="name">
```

And in the PHP that handles the form:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Side note, if you need to log in to comment, there's really no need for 'name' and 'email' as you can pull that data from the `$user->data()` method but that's your call.

[UserSpice - FUNctions](https://userspice.com/functions/)
[HTML5 Input Specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

Comment: Thank you but how do I add the above code if usespice is in another directory and my comment system is in the main directory

Comment: If UserSpice is working with your blog already, there's a catch somewhere (probably $_SESSION(S)) so you should be able to use the `$user` variable within your site as it seems to be a global variable.

Comment: Sorry I am reallu lost on figuring out this php stuff. Could you maybe send me an example of the above. Thanks in advance